# Google maps api v3 infowindow position in custom image

Tags: image, google-maps, infowindow

I implemented the v3 of google maps in my site. I created custom images to show points on the map.

One of the custom images is 120px X 120px size and i would like to point the arrow of infowindow in the center of this image and not on the top middle.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try using the pixelOffset option in InfoWindowOptions.

```
    myinfo = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ 
      content: "my content",
      pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, 60)
    });
    myinfo.open(map, marker);
```

Positive y-offset values send the InfoWindow down.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you very much Heitor!

Comment: How to make the y offset dynamic? based on the height, means, allways on top of the marker

Comment: @Hatim at any point, use `setOptions` to make dynamic changes, e.g.:       `this.myInfoWindow.setOptions({ pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, newHeightValue) })`